# Running same gradle task with different parameters in parallel?

Tags: gradle, gatling-plugin

I would like to run two `gatlingRun` tasks (created by gatling gradle plugin) with different parameters (on 2 environments) at the same time.

I know that new gradle provides Worker API, but this seems to be not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, Gradle [Worker API](https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/) is not really applicable in your case because it enables parallel processing, but in the context of a single *Task*, as the documentation states:

> The Worker API provides the ability to break up the execution of a task action into discrete units of work and then to execute that work concurrently and asynchronously.

In order to make different tasks run in parallel, you could maybe use [Parallel execution](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#parallel_execution) feature. But note that you can run tasks in parallel only if when they belong to different sub-projects (of a same multi-project build):

> Most builds consist of more than one project and some of those projects are usually independent of one another. Yet Gradle will only run one task at a time by default, regardless of the project structure (this will be improved soon). By using the --parallel switch, you can force Gradle to execute tasks in parallel as long as those tasks are in different projects.

If your build script is used "only" as a launcher for Gatlin load tests, then maybe you can implement your build script as a multi-projects  build, with one sub-project per target environment to test; then you could enable the `--parallel` option to execute the load test tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

@M.Ricciuti is wrong on Worker API abilities.

Gradle's documentation is vague on this, but [I asked and got the answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/can-we-run-tasks-in-parallel-in-single-build-project/18321/10) that Worker API really allows us to run several tasks in parallel in the same project.

This is a working example, with tasks of different classes:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

class Sleeping5 extends DefaultTask {
  static class Sleeper5 implements Runnable {
    String name
    @Inject
    public Sleeper5(String name) {
      this.@name = name
    }
    @Override
    void run() {
      (1..50).each { int i ->
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println "$name: $i"
      }
    }
  }
  private final WorkerExecutor workerExecutor
  @Inject
  public Sleeping5(WorkerExecutor workerExecutor) {
    this.workerExecutor = workerExecutor
  }
  @TaskAction
  void sleep() {
    workerExecutor.submit(Sleeper5, new Action<WorkerConfiguration>() {
      @Override
      void execute(WorkerConfiguration config) {
        config.isolationMode = IsolationMode.NONE
        config.displayName = name
        config.params = [name]
      }
    })
  }
}

class Sleeping10 extends DefaultTask {
  static class Sleeper10 implements Runnable {
    String name
    @Inject
    public Sleeper10(String name) {
      this.@name = name
    }
    @Override
    void run() {
      (1..70).each { int i ->
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println "$name: $i"
      }
    }
  }
  private final WorkerExecutor workerExecutor
  @Inject
  public Sleeping10(WorkerExecutor workerExecutor) {
    this.workerExecutor = workerExecutor
  }
  @TaskAction
  void sleep() {
    workerExecutor.submit(Sleeper10, new Action<WorkerConfiguration>() {
      @Override
      void execute(WorkerConfiguration config) {
        config.isolationMode = IsolationMode.NONE
        config.displayName = name
        config.params = [name]
      }
    })
  }
}
task(type: Sleeping5, 'sleep5')
task(type: Sleeping10, 'sleep10')
```

Assuming you have multi-core CPU or set `gradle.workers.max` property, tasks `sleep5` and `sleep10` run in parallel.

But, on your actual case, it is still not feasible.

Worker API should be used from task implementation, and [GatlingRunTask](https://github.com/lkishalmi/gradle-gatling-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/lkishalmi/gradle/gatling/GatlingRunTask.groovy) is not using it.

You or plugin author have to rewrite task implementation to use Worker API inside.